# Why Linux booting on same system doesn't take same amount of time always?

Tags: linux, boot

I've observed that booting Fedora 28 with Mate Desktop takes 7-10 seconds of time on my laptop. The booting time varies arbitrarily between 7 to 10 seconds. There was absolutely no changes, no updates etc between all these measurements. And same `kernel` file, same `initramfs`, and same `grub` configuration were also used.

I'm wondering if there is any reason for this arbitrary variation of booting time?

**Note** I've measured the booting time from messages appearing on `tty` before `gdm` starts. For that, I disabled `rhgb quiet` mode from `grub` configuration. I always observed the time of the last message appearing before `gdm` starts. And the last message was always same.

Comment: There are ways to profile the boot and see exactly where the time is spent. As for reasons, who knows? Are you using the network? Are you using DHCP? Those alone could potentially account for the variation. Are you testing at a fixed location (your house, your school, your workplace)? How busy is the network? Are you using wired or wireless? If the latter, how well maintained is the wireless environment? I could probably come up with tens more questions like this that could make a difference.

Comment: @Nick I'm using network and DHCP. I'm testing from the same location and with same the network (network from the same ISP). Using wireless. I think the network is not very busy. Wireless is well maintained (in terms of good signal and power supply etc) by me. May you please give me some more insights on how to proceed to detect exactly what is causing the variation?

Comment: I suspect that there are random delays in the network. In any case, `bootchart` can be used to measure the time for various stages of boot. There is some information on how to install it and run it [here](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Bootchart).